# \biboptions with cas-dc does not work

Tags: natbib, els-cas

Hey Guys I am using the `cas-dc` DocumentClass and I would like to use sort&compress from natbib with my citation.

According to there guiedlines I can use `\biboptions{sort&compress}` but that dos not work as `\biboptions` is not recognized.

The download is here: mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip
In case someone needs it.

Anyone know a solution for that problem

Comment: I saw that post as well, but I am using cas-dc and not elsevier. ALthough I believe it should work the same it does not.

Comment: That's what the other post is about: The `\biboptions` command *only* exists in `elsarticle`, since you are not using it you have to pas `sort&compress` directly as an argument to `natbib` (See the answer of Jahannes_B) If you want more details on how t do that in your document, we will need to see a minimal working example to see how you are loading the packages involved.

Comment: Instead of `\biboptions{sort&compress}`, try `\setcitestyle{numbers,sort&compress}`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger actually in the manual for the cas-dc the \biboptions is also named as an way to pass natbib option